# Why are the sines and cosines of something resulting in the wrong anser?

Tags: trigonometry

For any developers, I use the following code:

```
double zpos = cli.z;
double xpos = cli.x;
zpos += Math.cos(Math.toRadians(cli.rotation)) * 7.5;
xpos += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(cli.rotation)) * 7.5;
```

Which to translate to non-coders, 
cli.x (The X location of a ship) + sin(cli.rotation (The rotation, in degrees)) * 7.5 (The distance required to get it to the location I want).

But for some reason, when rotation is different, the result is becoming different as well.

This is setting the location for my cannonballs to fire - And when the ship is at 45 degrees, the cannonballs all seem to spawn in a line sideways to the ship. But when at 0 degrees, they spawn in perfectly the correct location. At 90 degrees, they also appear to spawn correctly.

What is wrong with the above code? I know for certain that is the troublesome code, since if I remove the xpos+=......, then they spawn at the ship's actual location.

So, what is wrong with it? I cannot work it out.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls2jviMGjIw

Comment: maybe can you put some visual of your problem?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls2jviMGjIw

Look at when I fire the cannonballs at different angles.
Where the video starts off is 0 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the coordinates of the ship are $(x_0, z_0)$ . You want to find a new point, which is distant $L$ from the ship, and that forms a direction $\theta$, I assume $\theta$ is calculated counterclockwise.

Then the coordinates of the new point are $$x_1 = x_0 + L \cos \theta$$$$z_1 = z_0 + L \sin \theta$$

The only "wrong" thing I see is that you switched $\sin$ and $\cos$ in your code, but of course it all depends on the meaning of $x$ and $z$. If $x$ is actually meant to represent the horizontal axis, then you should switch $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Having said so, it is unlikely that this will resolve the problem, because it would have had an effect on angles of $0$ and $90$ degrees, but it would have yield the correct answer for $45$ degrees, because at $45$ degrees $\sin$ and $\cos$ are equal.

But the mathematical problems ends here, either you add more info or you post the problem on stackoverflow :)

Comment: So... My lines of code are correct? That is crazy!

Comment: @Joehot200 as long as I can see they are! Try add some new informations.. Like, what do you mean sideways? Where exactly?

Comment: Added video to OP.

Answer (score 0):

[image: [2]]

Now you want the bullets to go in a straight line perpendicular to the ship (i.e. $\bf OA$)

Let $\bf OC$ be $\bf X-axis$ and line perpendicular to it as $\bf Y-axis$.

Now if we want the bullet to move $\bf dl$ ($>0$) in one loop(iteration of a block of code) or simply one unit time( which will change based on your programs' $\bf FPS$.)

When the ship is at an angle $\theta$ to $\bf X-axis$
Then the components of it along perpendicular axes are:
$${\bf dx}={\bf dl}\cos(\pi/2+\theta)=-{\bf dl}\sin\theta$$
$${\bf dy}={\bf dl}\sin(\pi/2+\theta)={\bf dl}\cos\theta$$

Now you'll do something like this:

```
public void move(){
float angle = Math.toRadians(ship.getRotation());
final float dl =7.5;
X_pos -= dl * Math.sin(angle);
Y_pos += dl * Math.cos(angle);
bulletPool.move(X_pos,Y_pos);
}
```

Or a more general approach:

```
float angle = Math.pi / 2 + Math.toRadians(ship.getRotation());
final float dl =7.5;
X_pos += dl * Math.cos(angle);
Y_pos += dl * Math.sin(angle);
bulletPool.move(X_pos,Y_pos);
}
```